# interactions in logistical regression R

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I am struggling to interpret the results of a binomial logistic regression I did. The experiment has 4 conditions, in each condition all participants receive different version of treatment.
DVs (1 per condition)=DE01,DE02,DE03,DE04, all binary (1 - participants take a spec. decision, 0 - don't)
Predictors: FTFinal (continuous, a freedom threat scale)
            SRFinal (continuous, situational reactance scale)
            TRFinal (continuous, trait reactance scale)
            SVO_Type(binary, egoists=1, altruists=0)
After running the binomial (logit) models, I ended up with the following:[see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAyBT.png). Initially I tested 2 models per condition, when condition 2 (DE02 as a DV) got my attention. In model(3)There are two variables, which are significant predictors of DE02 (taking a decision or not) - FTFinal and SVO Type. In context, the values for model (3) would mean that all else equal, being an Egoist (SVO_Type 1) decreases the (log)likelihood of taking a decision in comparison to being an altruist. Also, higher scores on FTFinal(freedom threat) increase the likelihood of taking the decision. So far so good. Removing SVO_Type from the regression (model 4) made the FTFinal coefficient non-significant. Removing FTFinal from the model does not change the significance of SVO_Type.
 
So I figured:ok, mediaiton, perhaps, or moderation. 
I tried all models both in R and SPSS, and entering an interaction term SVO_Type*FTFinal makes !all variables in model(2) non-significant. I followed this "http: //www.nrhpsych.com/mediation/logmed.html" mediation procedure for logistic regression, but found no mediation. (sorry for link, not allowd to post more than 2, remove space after http:) 
 To sum up:
 Predicting DE02 from SVO_Type only is not significant.
Predicting DE02 from FTFinal is not significant
Putitng those two in the regression makes them significant predictors
code and summaries [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A5Ze.png)
Including an interaction between these both in a model makes all coefficients insignificant.

So I am at a total loss: As far as I know, to test moderation, you need an interaction term. This term is between a categorical var (SVO_Type) and the continuous one(FTFinal), perhaps that goes wrong?
And to test mediation outside SPSS, I tried the "mediate" package (sorry I am a noob, so I am allowed max 3 links per post), only to discover that there is a "treatment" argument in the funciton, which is to be the treatment variable (exp Vs cntrl). I don't have such, all ppns are subjected to different versions of the same treatment.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) question.

Comment: Dear user2100721, I cannot link more than 2 items with my reputation. The dataset is here: http://www.filedropper.com/final_24 <br><br>And the code here: http://www.filedropper.com/stack_1

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question about programming at all. It seems like a question about statistical model fitting. If that's the case, such questions belong on [stats.se], not Stack Overflow. But the question still really needs a reproducible example in the question itself. Don't link to data externally because those links will often break in the future. The question should be self contained.

Comment: I would recommend to move to Cross Validated, and post the model (as formula).    You seem to be doing a straightforward logit, can you boil it down to two models that reflect the problem?

Comment: Hi, I moved the post to Cross Validated, if you guys wanna follow up. Should I remove it from here, or it is better to link it?